# is there an option to update multipass image version

Tags: multipass

i am using multipass (version 1.6.2) to launch ubuntu instances. when looking at [`multipass find`](https://multipass.run/docs/find-command) output, it lists the version of each image.

```sh
$ multipass find
Image                       Aliases           Version          Description
snapcraft:core18                              20201111         Snapcraft builder for Core 18
snapcraft:core20                              20201111         Snapcraft builder for Core 20
snapcraft:core                                20210224         Snapcraft builder for Core 16
16.04                       xenial            20210224         Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
18.04                       bionic            20210224         Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
20.04                       focal,lts         20210223         Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
20.10                       groovy            20210209         Ubuntu 20.10
```

at the first time an instance is launched, multipass pulls the image and it does so only once, even if the instance is [deleted](https://multipass.run/docs/working-with-instances) and recreated.

can the images be updated? and if so, how to force multipass to update the images?